# Find the boundaries of a text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

## My Question

Is it possible to get the boundaries of a text with JavaScript?

For example:

[image]

I want to get only the red marked area.

## Why I'm Asking

I'm working on a wordcloud and want to be able to place new words inside a word's div, without overlapping the actual text.

For example:

[image]

I want to be able to place new words in the red marked areas, but my overlap-checking function won't recognize those areas as "free", since i currently use the word's div's boundaries (as shown in the black frame).

Comment: Paint it on a canvas, use some kind of floodfill with a larger radius to generate the outline.

Comment: I don't see any straightforward way of doing that, other than defining the dimensions for every single letter

Comment: The free area above/below the letters like on the 2nd image can probably be determined by wrapping each letter in individual `span`, checking if each letter is lowercase and isn't one of the letters with ascenders/descenders, and if so, treat space below the baseline and above `1ex` above the baseline in that span as "free". But it won't help to find free space like that under the left stroke of "T" in the 1st example.

Comment: @Bergi Could you give an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a span to the places where you want to place a text, give this an id then read this id with javascript and paste the text into the span. As shown here:

Html:

```
<span id='mySpan'><span>
```

Javascript:

```
let span = document.getElementById("mySpan");
span.text = "example";
```

Comment: Thanks, but the texts and their locations are made dynamically, so i can't predict them.